# Can you divide a square into triangles

Tags: geometry

Can you divide a square into triangles, so that every single triangle would have a common (not necessary **entire**) side with exactly three other triangles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible.

One solution is start from a $5 \times 5$ square.
On each side, draw a $3 \times 4$ right angled triangle. This leaves
us with a $1 \times 1$ square in the middle. Cut the small square along a diagonal. This gives us following division of original square into $6$ triangles.

If one ignore contact at the vertices, each triangle is touching 3 other
triangles along the sides.

$\hspace1.5in$ [image: 6 triangles in 1 square]